# Google Music Beta: Thumbs Up and Down Now Playing using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on my first extension for Google Chrome. I want to be able to hit the "Thumbs Up" button on the Google Music Beta page using my extension. For some reason, the thumbs up button seems to be much more complicated than shuffle, repeat, play, next, and previous. For all of those, the following code works:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab_id,
            {
              code: "location.assign('javascript:SJBpost(\"" + command +
                    "\");void 0');",
              allFrames: true
            });
```

where command="playPause", "nextSong", "prevSong", "toggleShuffle", "togglePlay", etc.

I figured a lot of those out using the developer tools to follow the stack trace and see the arguments given to SJBpost. Trying SJBpost with "thumbsUp" returns an error.

Obviously this question is going to be restricted to a smaller crowd since not everyone is going to be able to view the source of Google Music, but if you can help me out, I would greatly appreciate it.

The div for the thumbs up on the Google Music page looks like this:

```
<div id="thumbsUpPlayer" class="thumbsUp" title="Thumbs up"></div>
```

Now, I've tried doing this using jQuery:

```
$("#thumbsUpPlayer").click()
```

But I get TypeError, undefined_method message in the javascript console.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am a huge beginner to javascript and plugins, and all of this stuff, and I'm really excited to get these last pieces of the extension together.

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to trigger a click, then do `.trigger('click');`

Comment: That still gives me a TypeError non_object_property_call... Could multiple versions of jQuery be conflicting with each other?

Comment: What versions are you loading?

Comment: 1.5.1, 1.4.2, 1.5.2, 1.5.1 all get loaded by different extensions already running. Do these conflict with one another?

Comment: Each extension runs in a different sandbox, just like each tab. What versions of jQuery are **you** using?

Comment: I am using 1.5.2. If I try doing .click(), or even .trigger('click') on my extensions own elements, it works fine, but as soon as I try to do it within my content script it fails. jQuery is getting injected though.

Comment: I just checked the source and it looks like jQuery does support short hand triggering, which is good to know. Sadly, I don't know anything about the Google Music API (or really, even Google Music) or making Chrome Extensions. Good luck though.

Comment: Not a problem. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Some questions... 1. Could use a content (injected) script rather than chrome.tabs.executeScript()? 2. Is $("thumbsUpPlayer") defined when you call $("thumbsUpPlayer").click()? 3. Are you sure clicking Thumbs Up actually calls SJBpost()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Google Music Beta doesn't actually listen on the `click()` event per se, rather, it is based on the events which usually precede the actual click event: mouseover, mousedown and mouseup.

I'm not a jQuery expert, so I can't exactly figure out why `$("#thumbsUpPlayer").mouseover().mousedown().mouseup()` doesn't work (neither does doing `.trigger`).

Anyway, here's some (tested on June 21) working javascript code (no dependencies).

```
function triggerMouseEvent(element, eventname){
    var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    event.initMouseEvent(eventname, true, true, document.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, element);
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
}

function replicateClick(element){
    triggerMouseEvent(element, 'mouseover');
    triggerMouseEvent(element, 'mousedown');
    triggerMouseEvent(element, 'mouseup');
}

function thumbsUp(){
    replicateClick(document.getElementById('thumbsUpPlayer'));
}

function thumbsDown(){
    replicateClick(document.getElementById('thumbsDownPlayer'));
}
```

It should be probably fairly easy to use, just call `thumbsUp()` if you want a thumbs up or call `thumbsDown()` if you want to thumbs down.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I can tell I'm close. I just tried it without modifying the code at all, but I'm getting an error: 
UncaughtTypeError: Cannot call method 'dispatchEvent' of null
This would be your 4th line of code in the block. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind! It works now that you have modified my source using this line:
`location.assign("javascript:(function(element){'over,down,up'.split(',').forEach(function(i){var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');event.initMouseEvent('mouse'+i, true, true, document.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, element);element.dispatchEvent(event)})})(document.getElementById('"+element+"'))");`
Where element is either "thumbsUpPlayer" or "thumbsDownPlayer"

Thank you!

Comment: Worked just fine for me :) its now in Better Music Beta!

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking into this today and found that you can trigger a lot of the commands using SJBpost from the console.

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110622061755509

```
SJBpost('thumbsUpPlayer');
```

Commands I've tried and can confirm working:

1. playPause
2. thumbsUpPlayer
3. thumbsDownPlayer
4. prevSong
5. nextSong

I'm still looking into commands which let you retrieve current artist / track info. Let me know if you find out what those are.

Comment: These seem to have all stopped working for me. 'prevSong' stopped working months ago and 'playPause' just stopped working this week. Does anybody know what a more current solution would be?

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet from the ['music plus for google'](https://github.com/adampash/Music-Plus-for-Google-Music/blob/be0d0a89039f190f1c7b1d7a66c38869ebc24b7d/scripts/myscript.js)  chrome extension might be of interest:

```
function playback_action(type, callback) {
  var $button;
  if (type == 'playPause') {
    $button = $('button[data-id="play-pause"]');
  }
  else if (type == 'nextSong') {
    $button = $('button[data-id="forward"]');
  }
  else if (type == 'prevSong') {
    $button = $('button[data-id="rewind"]');
  }
  else if (type == 'currently_playing') {
    $button = $('button[data-id="play-pause"]');
  }
  if ($('button[data-id="play-pause"]').attr('disabled')) {
    $instant_mix = $('li[data-type="rd"]').click();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('div[data-type="im"] .radio-icon').first().click();
    }, 1000);
  }
  else {
    $button.click();
  }
  callback();
}
```

When the above snippet stops working, check the link again and see if maybe the author updated the extension to something that works.